# Exception Handling ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using `ScheduledExecutorService` to run threads at a fixed interval of `1 min`.

One instance of `ScheduledExecutorService` runs one thread and another instance runs another thread.

**Example:**

```java
ses1.scheduleAtFixRate(..) // for thread 1  
ses2.scheduleAtFixRate(..) // for thread 2
```

I was encountering some exceptions by which the further execution stops. I want to catch the exception for a systematic shutdown of my application.

**Should I handle the exception using a third thread** that monitors both futures and handles the Exception or is there any other better way? Will it affect the other threads.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was encountering some exceptions by which the further execution
>   stops.

That is the expected behavior of `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixRate()` according to the specification :

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed.

About your need :

> I want to catch the exception for a systematic shutdown of my
>   application.
>   Should I handle the exception using a third thread that monitors both
>   futures and handles the Exception or is there any other better way?

Handling the future return with `ScheduledFuture.get()` looks the right. 
According to `ScheduledFuture.scheduleAtFixedRate()` specification :

> Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or
>   termination of the executor.

So you don't even need to create a new scheduled future.
Just run two parallel tasks (with `ExecutorService` or two threads is also possible) that wait on `get()` of each `Future` and that stops the application in case of exception thrown in the task  :

```
Future<?> futureA = ses1.scheduleAtFixRate(..) // for thread 1  
Future<?> futureB = ses2.scheduleAtFixRate(..) // for thread 2
submitAndStopTheApplicationIfFail(futureA);
submitAndStopTheApplicationIfFail(futureB);

public void submitAndStopTheApplicationIfFail(Future<?> future){
      executor.submit(() -> {
      try {
        future.get();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // stop the application
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // stop the application
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: This way though it gets stuck at future1.get(). If the second thread encounters an exception this method won't work. It will wait for first thread to get  complete.

Comment: It is right. The two should be in their own execution thread to make `.get()` no blocking. I updated.  Tell me whether it is better.

Comment: Did the same thing while I was fixing it but Thanks. Great Help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably don't need two separate executors ses1 and ses2 for each task, just create one ses1 with corePoolSize = 2.
And here is how I deal with handling exceptions and completion of all scheduled tasks:

1. Create the wrapper method for ScheduledExecutor's futures

```
private static @NotNull CompletableFuture<Void> wrapFuture(Future<?> future){
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (t instanceof ExecutionException ee){
                throw new CompletionException(ee.getCause());
            }
            throw new CompletionException(t);
        }
    });
}
```

2. Then schedule tasks and wrap them into the CompletableFutures

```
var ses = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);

var f1 = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::processQueue, 100, 25, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
var f2 = ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::prefetch, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

var cf1 = wrapFuture(f1);
var cf2 = wrapFuture(f2);
```

3. Handle exceptions along with termination

```
CompletableFuture.anyOf(cf1, cf2).whenCompleteAsync((o, t) -> {
    if (t != null && !(t.getCause() instanceof CancellationException)){
        System.err.println("Exception in ScheduledExecutor task: " + t);
        ses.shutdownNow();
        try {
            ses.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
    System.out.println("All tasks completed");
});
```

One drawback: if you need to cancel resulting completable future it may stuck on awaitTermination(), make sure the tasks itself can properly respond to cancellation via executor shutdown.